# HP DL380 RAID5 Mistake

Tags: hp, raid5, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I had drives fail in both logical drives on a server.  When I replaced failed 146GB drive in Raid 5 array with four (4) 146GB drives.  On reboot the Smart Array controller asked if I wanted to accept data loss.  Guess mistake to choose yes.

Can't seem to find a way to get system to repair RAID5 but it seems to want to just create a new partition.

Is there anyway I can go back and get the system to restore the data from other three drives now that I said accept data loss?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is as follows:

1. remove all drives
2. start server up, clear the controller setup
3. power host down, insert drives as they were
4. power host up, go into controller bios
5. create a new raid5 exactly the way the old one was
   *make sure you do not reinitialise the new raid array!
6. mark the failed drive as offline
7. boot

This should take you into a booting degraded raid array. From here on you can replace the failed drive and assign the ew drive as hotspare, so it can rebuild the array

Comment: Thanks for help, thought there might be a way to fix.  Couple of quick questions.  From instructions above, not sure what process is to:
when saying insert drives as they were mean the failed one rather than the replacement and in same slots?
"clear the controller setup" - does this just happen automatically on boot?
"create a new raid5" - does this mean set up new logical drive and name same?
how do you keep from reinitializing ?  Answer no to accept data loss?
How do you mark failed drive offline?
Sorry, not familiar with the process, have not had drive in raid logical drive fail

Comment: the best thing you can do is call HP support and ask them to guide you through a re-tag procedure. That's what I have described above :)